# Google Maps Api v3 error

Tags: javascript, google-maps, kml

After further reading, trial and error and searching for solutions that i can get to fit has failed.

I have a KML file, which displays the locations I want, the serious problem is I can not figure out how to get the search input element to work with the Google Maps API.

I have tried onclick="findplace" 
But I can not get the infowindow to appear.

I am basically trying to add a search function to my list of maps (from the KML file) and not big list of places that Google places offer. Am starting to wonder if this is even possible as I can not find a an example online which is the same.

JavaScript is not a strong area for me, is there a way to make my custom map searchable?

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing you need to search through your list of locations in the KML file and you can't know in advance what exactly it contains. To do this you need to access the content of the KML file through the google maps API or directly from the file itself.

There doesn't seem to be any method to access the individual objects within a KML file (see discussions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2013393/how-to-get-the-kml-data-from-a-ggeoxml-object) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9195355/changing-kml-files-contents)) via the API. If the KML file originates from the same domain as your page then it would be possible to load the KML file and parse it as a straight XML file [(see here](http://www.w3schools.com/xml/xml_parser.asp)). Then you could search your parsed results and do what you need to do on the map (maybe send a click to the marker coordinate to show the infowindow). If it sits on another domain then you would need to retrieve the file via a server side call.

Does this sound like what you are trying to achieve?

Comment: Yeah this appears what I am after.So far I have a basic kml file online,the map loads the locations no problem with none selected.
The problem is how do i search the kml file with an input box to then bring up the infowindow of the found result. This is the part I can't figure out, i keep thinking back to mysql query on the submit, but i do not know javascript which am starting to think is required for this.  I have looked at examples and tried to edit the code and apply it to mine for days now,as it stands the map is not searchable via input element,but it can be used with all the locations.

Comment: One more question. When you say "search the kml file" what do you mean? Do you mean: search for a name in the file. If the kml file is a list of points representing cities (for example), do you want to search for the city names? Or is it that you want to find the nearest object (eg city) from a given location (eg centre of map)?

Comment: I think what am saying and meaning are different things. :(
Whilst the KML file is just an xml file with <marker> tags. When i say search i wanted the user to input a name or address into a input box. If the result is close to or matches a <marker> elements name/title attribute, then that location will be highlighed/ selected with the infowindow open and centred for that location.